# $N>n^2$ matrices are linearly indepednent $ A^N$

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Theorem**. Let A be an $n\times n$ matrix in a field $K$. Then there exists a non-zero polynomial $f\in K[t]$ such that $f(A)=0$.

**Proof**. The vector space of $n\times n$ matrices over $K$ is finite dimensional, of dimension $n^2$. Hence the powers $I, A,A^2,...,A^N$ are linearly dependent for $N> n^2$. This means that there exists numbers $a_0,...,a_n\in K$ such that not all $a_i=0$, and

$a_NA^N+...+a_0I=0$

We let $f(t)=a_Nt^N+...+a_0$ to get what we want.
**Linear Algebra, by Serge Lang**

**Question**:

"*The vector space of $n\times n$ matrices over $K$ is finite dimensional, of dimension $n^2$. Hence the powers $I, A,A^2,...,A^N$ are linearly dependent for $N> n^2$."* What does the author means? Is he saying that the dimension $n^2$ implies that the $I, A,A^2,...,A^N$ are linearly dependent for $N> n^2$? Why $N>n^2$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In a vector space, any set of vectors/matrices in the space larger than the dimension of the space are linearly dependent. Here you have $|\{I, A, A^2, ...,A^N\}|=N+1$

Comment: If a vector space is $n$-dimensional, every set of $n+1$ vectors is linearly dependent. $n \times n$ matrices form an $n^2$-dimensional vector space; hence, any set of $n^2 + 1$ matrices must be linearly dependent.

Comment: On another note, perhaps the author could/should've written '$N\ge n^2$'? Or am I missing something? (What he wrote isn't wrong, ofc, though)